# Error in loading CodeIgniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

[My site](http://maya3dmodels.com/index.php) was developed using CodeIgniter and was working fine before but now it's showing an error.

When I checked error log it's showing:

> [07-Jul-2012 09:17:11] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Suhosin Extension does not officially 
>   support PHP 5.2 and below anymore, because it is discontinued. Use it at your own risk. in 
>   Unknown on line 0
>   [07-Jul-2012 09:17:11] PHP Warning:
>   require(/home/maya3d/public_html/system/codeigniter/Common.php) [href='function.require'>function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/maya3d/public_html/system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php on line 38 [07-Jul-2012 09:17:11] PHP Fatal error:  require() [href='function.require'>function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/maya3d/public_html/system/codeigniter/Common.php' >   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/maya3d/public_html/system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php on line 38

Can anyone please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into the server and run:

`ls -l /home/maya3d/public_html/system/codeigniter/Common.php`

If it says the file doesn't exist then there's your problem.  It could be permissions related as well.

Comment: I might also suggest disabling Suhosin, per the warning.